# Find array value

Tags: javascript, arrays

My array:

```
var PrivateChatList = [];
```

And push key and value (just example):

```
PrivateChatList['supporter1'] = 'player1';
PrivateChatList['supporter2'] = 'player2';
PrivateChatList['supporter3'] = 'player3';
PrivateChatList['supporter4'] = 'player4';
PrivateChatList['supporter5'] = 'player5';
PrivateChatList['supporter6'] = 'player6';
PrivateChatList['supporter7'] = 'player7';
```

I want to find "player4" key on function. How can i find ?

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getObjectKeyFromValue(object, value)
{
    for(var k in object)
    {
        if(object[k] == value)
        {
            return k;
        }
    }
    return '';
}

var key = getObjectKeyFromValue(PrivateChatList, 'player4')
alert(key); // 'supporter4'
```